# how to add spacing between each sound effect when running array through for loop

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript and I came across a question I couldn't find an answer to. I am trying to store whatever a user presses into the array record and from there, replay the sound effects that the user had previously pressed. My problem is, it plays everything all at once when I run it through the for loop. Could someone guide me in the right direction as to how to resolve my problem?

```js
var drumButton = document.querySelectorAll(".drum").length;
var record = [];

for (var i = 0; i < drumButton; i++) {
  document.querySelectorAll(".drum")[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    var buttonInnerHTML = this.innerHTML;
    record.push(buttonInnerHTML);
    makeSound(buttonInnerHTML);
    
  });
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event){
  record.push(event.key);
  makeSound(event.key);
})

function makeSound(key){
  switch (key) {
    case "w":
      var tom1 = new Audio("sounds/tom-1.mp3");
      tom1.play();
      break;
    case "a":
      var tom2 = new Audio("sounds/tom-2.mp3");
      tom2.play();
      break;

    case "s":
      var tom3 = new Audio("sounds/tom-3.mp3");
      tom3.play();
      break;
    case "d":
      var tom4 = new Audio("sounds/tom-4.mp3");
      tom4.play();
      break;

    case "j":
      var snare = new Audio("sounds/snare.mp3");
      snare.play();
      break;
    case "k":
      var kickBass = new Audio("sounds/kick-bass.mp3");
      kickBass.play();
      break;
    case "l":
      var crash = new Audio("sounds/crash.mp3");
      crash.play();
      break;

    default:
      console.log(buttonInnerHTML);
  }
}

function clearReplay(){
  while(record.length)
    record.pop();
}

function replay(){
  for(var i=0; i < record.length; i++){
    makeSound(record[i]);
    
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #283149;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 5rem;
  color: #DBEDF3;
  font-family: "Arvo", cursive;
  text-shadow: 3px 0 #DA0463;

}

footer {
  color: #DBEDF3;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.w {
  background: url('images/tom1.png');
}

.a {
  background: url('images/tom2.png');
}

.s {
  background: url('images/tom3.png');
}

.d {
  background: url('images/tom4.png');
}

.j {
  background: url('images/snare.png');
}

.k {
  background: url('images/kick.png');
} 

.l {
  background: url('images/crash.png');
}

.set {
  margin: 10% auto;
}

.game-over {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.pressed {
  box-shadow: 0 3px 4px 0 #DBEDF3;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}

.drum {
  outline: none;
  border: 10px solid #404B69;
  font-size: 5rem;
  font-family: 'Arvo', cursive;
  line-height: 2;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #DA0463;
  text-shadow: 3px 0 #DBEDF3;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Drum Kit</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <h1 id="title">Drum  Kit</h1>
  <div class="set">
    <button class="w drum">w</button>
    <button class="a drum">a</button>
    <button class="s drum">s</button>
    <button class="d drum">d</button>
    <button class="j drum">j</button>
    <button class="k drum">k</button>
    <button class="l drum">l</button>
  </div>
  
  <button class="record" onclick="replay()">replay</button>
  <button class="clear" onclick="clearReplay()">clear</button>
  <script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can **delay** the audio playback using the `setTimeout()` function. For that, you need to make changes to `relay()` function like so:

```
function replay() {
  duration = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < record.length; i++) {
    /* Delay playback of audio */

    setTimeout(() => {
      makeSound(record[i]);
    }, duration);

    /* Add the duration of current audio to the total duration */

    duration += record[i].duration
  }
}
```

Here we use `setTimeout()` to delay the playback of the audio based on the variable `duration` instead of directly playing the audio. The duration of each audio element is added to `duration` iteratively to delay the playback of the successive audio.

Comment: After trying out the code and testing different possibilities, it still plays it all at once but with a slight delay in the beginning. If I add the following code that you've written, it shows that the duration is undefined.